# Storing Char and using it in if-statements

Tags: c

I just wanna know how to save or store a symbol such as +, -, / and * so that i could use it in if-statements to perform whatever symbol the user inputs. I know that my code is wrong so any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int int1, int2, sum;
    char oper;
    printf("Enter Value Here: ");
    scanf("%d", &int1);
    printf("Enter Operation Here: ");
    scanf("%s", &oper);
    printf("Enter Value Here: ");
    scanf("%d", &int2);
    if (oper == "+")
        sum = int1 + int2;
    printf("The sum is %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare strings ( not string addresses, which will be different )

Comment: Like any other language feature, you need to actually study strings before using them.

Comment: could you elaborate what is strcmp and how to use it?

Comment: Could you just read a C book? SO is not a teaching site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int int1, int2, sum=0;
    char op;


    printf("Please enter one of the following Operators [*] [/] [+] [-]   ");
    if((scanf("%c",&op)) != 1){
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    printf("Enter Value Here: ");
    if((scanf("%d", &int1)) != 1){
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    printf("Enter Value Here: ");
    if((scanf("%d", &int2)) != 1){
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    if (op == '/'){
        sum = int1 / int2;
    }else if(op == '*'){
        sum = int1 * int2;
    }else if(op == '+'){
        sum = int1 + int2;
    }else if(op == '*'){
        sum = int1 - int2;
    }

    printf("The sum is %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
For a better precision you can use **float** or **double**, Use **double** if you are not sure.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    float int1, int2, sum=0;
    char op;


    printf("Please enter one of the following Operators [*] [/] [+] [-]   ");
    if((scanf("%c",&op)) != 1){
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    printf("Enter Value Here: ");
    if((scanf("%f", &int1)) != 1){
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    printf("Enter Value Here: ");
    if((scanf("%f", &int2)) != 1){
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    if (op == '/'){
        sum = int1 / int2;
    }else if(op == '*'){
        sum = int1 * int2;
    }else if(op == '+'){
        sum = int1 + int2;
    }else if(op == '*'){
        sum = int1 - int2;
    }

    printf("The sum is %.1f\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very much appreciated. Thank you very much! But I have one last question,  do i really have to use ' instead of " when comparing char?

Comment: If you use a single quote, then you are implying a single character. However double quotes makes it a string which is sequence of chars enclosed in the double quotes terminated by NULL character.

Comment: Short anser, **'** is use for single chararcter and **"** is used for strings

Comment: this was never been taught to us. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `switch` case in `C`:

```
    char oper;
    float num1,num2;
    printf("Enter operator either + or - or * or / : ");
    scanf("%c",&oper);
    printf("Enter two operands: ");
    scanf("%f%f",&num1,&num2);
    switch(oper) {
        case '+':
            printf("%.1f + %.1f = %.1f",num1, num2, num1+num2);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("%.1f - %.1f = %.1f",num1, num2, num1-num2);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("%.1f * %.1f = %.1f",num1, num2, num1*num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("%.1f / %.1f = %.1f",num1, num2, num1/num2);
            break;
        default:
            /* If operator is other than +, -, * or /, error message is shown */
            printf("Error! operator is not correct");
            break;
    }
```

now using `if-else`:

```
 //same code
 scanf("%f%f",&num1,&num2);
            if(oper=='+')
                printf("%.1f + %.1f = %.1f",num1, num2, num1+num2);
            else if(oper=='-')
                printf("%.1f - %.1f = %.1f",num1, num2, num1-num2);
            else if(oper=='*')
                printf("%.1f * %.1f = %.1f",num1, num2, num1*num2);
            else if(oper=='/')
                printf("%.1f / %.1f = %.1f",num1, num2, num1/num2);
            else
                /* If operator is other than +, -, * or /, error message is shown */
                printf("Error! operator is not correct");
```

Comment: This was VERY helpful since our professor doesn't teach "practical" stuffs and makes us do programs without teaching anything. I'll try to study switch case but if ever I'm gonna use if-statements, how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: @RomsEsteban  gave you an  Answer.

Comment: If only I could  choose two best answer. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are looking for a function pointers that will let you do some object oriented programming:

```
// type of functions being binary operations
typedef int (binary_operation*)(int, int);

// now you can define any binary operation on ints

int add_op(int a, int b) { // definition };

int mul_op(int a, int b) { // definition };

// main...
    binary_operation f;
    if (oper == "+")
        f = add_op;
        sum = f(in1,int2);
```

This way you can store your functions in container, you can pass them to other functions and so on.